# How to do modular arithmetic with a negative n

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Playing with Python and the mod operation I encountered that (5 % -3) = -1. This is confirmed by [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%20mod%20-3), and I have not been able to find any simple explanation for this online, mostly because all I can find about modular arithmetic uses a positive `n`.

I am surprised by this result. My understanding of the modulo operation is that `a mod n` is a number `c` computed by taking the integer part `q = a / n`, and then substracting `n·q` from `a`.

Therefore, for `5 mod -3` I would do:

1. `q = int(5 / -3) = int(-1.6667) = -1`
2. `5 - (-3)·(-1) = 5 - 3 = 2`

Where am I wrong?

I have realised that -1 is congruent with 2 modulo -3, so maybe the answer is that the result must be between 0 and n, so if n is negative we need to add `n` to the positive result, but not sure if this is really the reason.

Please consider that I am not a mathematician, so the simpler the explanation the better.

Comment: you should consider x%y = x-(x//y*y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An integer is divisible by 3 if and only if it is divisible by -3. The usual definition of congruence mod 3 is that $a\equiv_3 b$ if and only if $3\mid a-b$ (i.e if and only if $a-b$ is divisible by 3). So you have the same structure mod 3 and mod -3. The reason they didnt give you 2 as your answer is probably because they want to choose representatives from the set $\{0,-1,-2\}$.

Comment: This was something I encountered in a test in uni, and 2 was given as a possible answer in the test, but it was not the right answer. I assume the reason is the one you mention and that I suspected: they expect answers in the set between 0 and n, despite not making it explicit.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the two answers $-1$ and $2$. These are the same modulo $-3$.

Note that $-1=2+(-3)$.

Comment: I see. I was curious about this because they showed up in a single-answer test in university, and the options were `2`, `-1` and `1`, and `-1` was marked as the valid answer. I assume the issue is that maybe the result needs to be between 0 and n, so if n is negative one need to add n to the result to bring it to the accepted range, but this was never made explicit anywhere, so I assumed there was a deeper mathematical reason for -1 being the right answer instead of 2.

Comment: Your suggestion for why -1 was chosen is feasible but it should have been made clear in the question!

Comment: Also % is remainder in some languages not strictly mod. in Mod you can add a multiple of you modulus aftward and get the same amount. remainder if not taken again, will just add that multiple to your result.